# Regression - Interpretation of coefficents

Tags: regression, panel-data

I'm a bit stucked with a problem where I suppose the answer is rather simple.

I have a very simple regression model:

$x_{it} = x_{t-1} + \beta_i P_i(d_{it-1} - x_{it-1}) + \epsilon_{it}$

where $\beta$ basically measures the adjustment from the last observed value $x_{t-1}$ towards another observed value $d_{t-1}$ and $P_i$ is a dummy for different products.

In my case, $\beta$ typically lies between 0 and 1.

Now I have several products $i = 1,...,N$ I can compute the adjustment coefficient $\beta_i$ for and my goal is to explain how the different adjustment parameters depend on some product properties, $m_1,m_2$ for example. So easily spoken something like:

$\beta_i = \delta_0 + \delta_1m_{1i} + \delta_2m_{2i} + \epsilon_{i}$

From my understanding I can not regress on a regression coefficient, that just doesn't sound right. The most obvious would be to include interaction terms:

$x_{it} = x_{t-1} + (\delta_0 + \delta_1m_{1i} + \delta_2m_{2i} 
)P_i(d_{it-1} - x_{it-1}) + \epsilon_{it}$.

Is this the right approach meaning do the deltas explain the variation among the betas? Are there actually methods, with which I can actually estimate the deltas? FE/RE for example would estimate deltas for each product i, which is not what I want.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks a lot,

Chris

Comment: +1, interesting problem. It sounds a lot like something you can solve using hierarchical Bayesian methods if you are open to the Bayesian way.

Comment: Thanks, that's a very interesting idea. I will definitely check, if I can apply a hierarchical Bayesian model.

Answer (score 1):

You need to ask yourself the following two questions

A) The error term is $\varepsilon_{i}$ in both equations. I presume that's just a typo?

B) Why do you need $P_{i}$ if everything is already indexed by ${i}$?

In order to go from the first two equations to the third you need to assume that the error term in the second equation is zero - that is, the adjustment term $\beta_{i}$ depends non-stochastically on the product characteristics, which is definitely what I would do (if you don't, the model gets harder to identify and estimate and I don't know how much better it would fit your deta).

In terms of whether you can estimate the $\delta$s directly, the answer is definitely yes. In terms of how to do it, I only know how to do it in STATA, which has an excellent Maximum Likelihood engine (command mlexp) and that is how I would do it. If you choose to go down that route, you will need to make a distributional assumption on $\varepsilon_{it}$, and write its likelihood function in terms of the parameters and the observed variables.

Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer! A) sure, these are different $\epsilon_{it}$ and $\epsilon_{i}$ for all the regressions. B) you're also right, I mixed up the formal correct notation and how to implement it in R, the $P_i$ is pointless. I'm not sure, what exactly you mean by "assume that the error term in the second equation is zero", the assumption would be - as normally - $\epsilon_i ~ N(0,\sigma^2)$.

Comment: It means that 
$\beta_{i}=\delta_{1} M_{1i}+\delta_{2} M_{2i}$

which is what you are implicitly doing to get to equation 3 (otherwise where did the 2nd error go?)

Comment: Well, this is one of the problems I have. The error is reflected in the $\epsilon_{it}$ but this would imply that the error term and independent variable are correlated and hence impose problems on the model estimation.

Comment: First, to clarify your problem, I would distinguish the two error terms. Then, you need to decide wether you want the model for $\beta$ to be ($\beta_{i}=\delta_{0}+\delta_{1} m_{1i}+\delta_{1} m_{1i}$) or ($\beta_{i}=\delta_{0}+\delta_{1} m_{1i}+\delta_{1} m_{1i}+\varepsilon_{i}$) . OLS would only yield consistent estimates in the first case. The second case can still be dealt with in MLE, as I said above, but it would become way more involved to write the likelihood function: in particular, you would need to model the correlation between the two error terms (if any).